# CakePHP - Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, cakephp, oop, function, fatal-error

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getAvnet() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ems\app\controllers\queries_controller.php on line 23

The line is:

```
$ret = getAvnet('de', $searchstring);
```

supposedly calling

```
function getAvnet($country, $query)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use

```
$ret = $this->getAvnet('de', $searchstring);
```

In general you need to use `$this->` when accessing class methods and variables.

Read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Thank you very much for that! There seams to be something else I do totally incorrectly for getting these error messages:

Notice (8): Undefined variable: ret [APP\controllers\queries_controller.php, line 92]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: ret [APP\controllers\queries_controller.php, line 126]
Warning (2): array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given [APP\controllers\queries_controller.php, line 24]
Warning (2): array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given [APP\controllers\queries_controller.php, line 24]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Do you see what's happening there?

Comment: @Tim Edit your question and put the errors there, it's really hard to read as it is.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ret = $this->getAvnet('de', $searchstring);
```

Comment: try and explain more what you changed and why this helps